# MongoDB error 'host is not a valid option for Mongo::Connection' when rails development server is starting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I am getting an error when I start my rails development server. I run rails 3.0.6 and ruby 1.8.7 (2012-06-29 patchlevel 370) [i686-linux]

The console output is like this when I execute rails s

```
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 3.0.6 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
host is not a valid option for Mongo::Connection
```

My main concern is this error "host is not a valid option for Mongo::Connection". I integrate devise 1.5.2 to run Facebook, Twitter and LinkedIn login via Omniauth and this mongoDB error is appearing now.

The GemFile I use in this Rails App.

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.6'
gem 'rake', '0.8.7'

gem 'mysql'
gem 'mysql2', "0.2.11"

gem 'mongrel'
gem 'jquery-rails', '>= 0.2.7' 
gem 'active_scaffold_vho' 
gem 'inherited_resources', '~> 1.2.1' 
gem 'has_scope', '~> 0.5.0' 
gem 'json_pure' 
gem 'formtastic', '~> 1.2.3' 
gem "devise", "1.5.2"
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-linkedin'
gem 'omniauth-openid'
gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails' 

gem 'uuidtools', '~> 2.1.2'

gem 'capistrano', '~> 2.6.0' 

gem 'cgi_multipart_eof_fix'
gem 'fastthread'

gem 'mongoid', "~>2.0" #Mongoid
gem 'bson_ext', "~>1.3" #Mongoid

gem 'redis', "~> 2.2.0"
gem 'resque'
gem 'resque-scheduler'

gem 'SystemTimer', "~> 1.2.3" 

gem 'ar_mailer_rails3' 
gem 'lazy_high_charts', "~> 1.1.1" 

gem 'rails-breadcrumbs', "~> 1.0.0"

gem 'curb' 

gem 'geonames', "~> 0.2.2" 

gem 'activemerchant'

gem 'savon', "~> 0.9.7"

gem 'rack-ssl'
gem 'state_machine'

gem "http_accept_language", '~> 1.0.2'

gem 'recurly', '~> 2.1.0'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'

group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', "~> 2.8"
  gem 'rspec-mocks', "~> 2.8"
  gem 'capybara', "~> 0.4.1.2"
  gem 'database_cleaner', "~> 0.6.7 "
  gem 'cucumber', "~> 0.10.2"
  gem 'spork', "~> 0.9.0"
  gem 'launchy', "~> 0.4.0"
  gem 'machinist', "~> 1.0.6"
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', "1.3.0"
  gem 'faker', "~> 0.9.5"
  gem 'email_spec'  
  gem 'rails-erd'  
  gem 'ruby-debug'
end

group :development do
  gem "hirb"
  gem "awesome_print"
end
```

The mongoid.yml file is as follows:

```
defaults: &defaults
  host: localhost
  database: teenscrio

development:
  <<: *defaults
  database: teenscrio_dev

staging:
  <<: *defaults
  database: teenscrio_stg

test:
  <<: *defaults
  database: teenscrio_tst

# set these environment variables on your prod server
production:
  host: <%= ENV['MONGOID_HOST'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PORT'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['MONGOID_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PASSWORD'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['MONGOID_DATABASE'] %>
```

Why this error is appearing now? What is the relation between devise and mongoid? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reconsider how your initializing `Mongo::Connection`. You seem to be supplying the host [incorrectly in the options](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/master/lib/mongo/connection.rb#L534), whereas it has to be passed directly to the [initializer or specified in the environment](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/master/lib/mongo/connection.rb#L47).

I'm assuming there's some difference between your development and production environment with regards to how your constructing your MongoDB connection that's leading to the exception your encountering.

Comment: Is a mongo-ruby-driver problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: It's definitely an issue with how your initializing the connection. Perhaps if you'd post your initializer or environment scripts I can nail down the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It has to be removed from mongoid.yml

```
host: localhost
```

Then it does not show the error and it works fine.